# How to store a list of sets of three strings?

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string > >
```

can be used to store a list of a pair of strings. Is there a similar way to store a list of triplets of strings?

One way I can think of is to use `std::vector`

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string > > v (4, std::vector<std::string> (3));
```

but this will not allow me to use the handly `first` and `second` accessors.

So, I wrote my own class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class triad {
private:
    T* one;
    T* two;
    T* three;
public:
    triad() {  one = two = three =0;  }
    triad(triad& t) {
        one = new T(t.get1());
        two = new T(t.get2());
        three = new T(t.get3());
    }
    ~triad() {
        delete one;
        delete two;
        delete three;
        one = 0;
        two = 0;
        three = 0;
    }
    T& get1() { return *one; }
    T& get2() { return *two; }
    T& get3() { return *three; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector< triad<std::string> > v;
}
```

I have two questions

1. Can my class code be improved in any way?
2. Is there any better way to do store triplets of strings than the three ways described above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::tuple` is a generalization of `std::pair` that lets you store a collection of some size that you specify. So, you can say:

```
typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> Triad;
```

to get a type `Triad` that stores three strings.

Comment: `std::tuple` is new in C++11, but should be available in most compilers newer than a couple of years.

Answer (score 5):

You can use tuples from boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html

(In C++11 tuples are part of standard library: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Tuple_types)

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you should use `std::tuple` (or `boost::tuple`).  Nevertheless, I think there are things that you can learn from a critique of your code:

1. If you want something like `std::pair`, why didn't you write something that behaved like `std::pair`?  That is, a class with public data members that copies its items by value?
2. If you want something like `std::pair`, why not make it more generic like `std::pair`, where the different members can have different types?  Or if you care only about storing `std::string` members, why bother making it a template class?
3. Your copy constructor should take its argument by `const` reference.
4. You didn't follow the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).  You have a non-trivial copy constructor and a non-trivial destructor but neglected to implement a copy assignment operator.  However, if you did #1, you wouldn't need to worry about this.
5. As written, it is impossible to set your class's data members.  There is no constructor to initialize them with specified values, and there is no way to set them after construction. (If you try `triad.get1() = ...`, you'll crash trying to dereference a null pointer!)
6. Your constructors should initialize their data members using initialization lists.  For example:

   `triad() : one(0), two(0), three(0) { }`
7. One of the things that makes `std::pair` useful over simply making a `struct` of the desired members is that it comes with `operator==` and `operator<`.
8. If you really want to use accessor methods, then you should provide `const` versions.

Answer (score 1):

If your triad is specific then create a class, or at least a struct so you can give meaningful names to the members.

```
struct Contact
{
    std::string name;
    std::string nickname;
    std::string email;
};

std::vector<Contact> contacts;
```